# What permissions do I need to successfully install a Visual Studio setup project?

Tags: vb.net, permissions, setup-project, group-policy

I am new to Visual Studio development, but very familiar with VBA in Excel. I have a solution in Visual Studio 2019 consisting of a VB.NET forms app project and a setup project for the installer. I am trying to make a setup file to install the program on another laptop. I can publish the project, but when I run the setup.exe, it says successfully installed, even though the expected path and program files are not created. I believe it fails to create the install location within C:\Program Files (x86)\ as it does not have proper access, and the setup does not know the command failed.

Am I misunderstanding the use of the setup project? Does it not work with a Visual Basic project? Most of the tutorials I see are using C# forms app projects. I have followed several tutorials, but no dice.

I am an administrator on my laptop, but every now and then I need to contact IT to get access for some functions. Does anyone know specifically what group policy change would need to occur to allow for the install? Or, how to safely add an exception to allow my install without relaxing the policy globally? FYI, I get a green border around the form while the setup is running, regardless of 'Run as Administrator'.

For now, I am stuck with copying the Debug runtime executable to a laptop and double-clicking. It works, but I sometimes have issues with references and calls failing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Rafael

Windows 10 x64 22H2
Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Generally setups will either work or they will error, not say they worked but then don't.  Have you checked the windows event log?  Have you got the primary output for your project specified in the setup?

Comment: This sounds like a question for your IT support team. We have no idea what restrictions they have in place. It's possible that you didn't actually read the message during the installation process and didn't select the correct option(s). Unless your app is signed, one has to click a link to allow the installation.